# Enzyme / React Unit test

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine, enzyme

I have this React functional UI only component, which has two props passed in, the second being a function that is passed from its parent component. The onClick calls 'delegates' to a function in the parent container component, this parent method is then responsible for dispatching to a redux store.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const BotShowUI = ({ bot,  onClick  }) => {
    return(
        <div id={bot.id}  onClick={onClick}>
            {bot.id} : {bot.text}
        </div>
    )
}

BotShowUI.propTypes = {
   bot: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
   onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default BotShowUI;
```

My test spec is, which uses Jasmine

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import BotShowUI from '../botShowUI';

function onClickFunction(){};

describe('botShowUI', () =>  {

    const bot = {id: 1, isDone: false, text: 'bot 123'};
    const expectedDivText = '1 : bot 123';

    const wrapper = mount(<BotShowUI bot={bot} onClick={onClickFunction} />);

    it(' div has been rendered ', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('div').first()).not.toBe(null);
    });

    it(' div displays the correct bot text ', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('div').first().text()).toEqual(expectedDivText)
    });

    it(' div click event fired ', () => {
        wrapper.simulate('click');
        expect(wrapper.state('onClick')).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

This last assertion fails with

```
Chrome 57.0.2987 (Windows 10 0.0.0) botShowUI  div click event fired  FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClick' of null
            at ReactWrapper.state (webpack:///~/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:825:24 <- tests.webpack.js:26303:25)
            at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///app/react/components/bots/_tests/botShowUI.spec.js:25:23 <- tests.webpack.js:25415:25)
```

`wrapper.simulate('click');` works, but the next line fails
What is the correct way to assert that the click was fired ?
Do I have to drop into wrapper's props/children instead of using state ?

I'm not trying to test the parent container in any way, the two are isolated.
This test is only concerned with this UI component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that onClick isn't on state, but on props, so you will have to access it by doing `wrapper.props('onClick')`.

Secondly, to test whether onClick has been handled or not is to use a spy, rather than an empty function. If you do not want to use spy, you can still do that, but not the way you have done. If you are interested, I can post some pseudo-code for that too. But coming back to using spies, you can use a spy as the onClick prop. Below is the code for that. I have hand-written it, so please check for any syntax error, but you should get the idea on what needs to be done.

```
it('should call the onClick handler on click', () => {
  const onClickFunction = sinon.spy()
  wrapper = mount(<BotShowUI bot={bot} onClick={onClickFunction} />)
  wrapper.simulate('click');
  expect(onClickFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: Once again, thank you so much. I've upped your answer. And I've posted the solution for Jasmine

Answer (score 0):

Based on Abhishek's answer here's my solution for Jasmine

```
it(' div click event fired ', () => {

    let onClickFunction_spy = jasmine.createSpy('onClickFunction');
    const wrapper = mount(<BotShowUI bot={bot} onClick={onClickFunction_spy} />); 
    wrapper.simulate('click');
    expect(onClickFunction_spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Hope this helps anyone.